# Update date values in docs of Mongo Collection to ISODate format

Tags: mongodb, isodate

I have a Collection in Mongo data store, for which I have docs which have a value as below.

```
{
    "_id" : "ABC-98765432",
    "Prospects" : [ 
        {
            "emailAddress":"test1@test.com",
            "dateOfBirth" : Date(-62135751600000)
        }, 
        {
            "emailAddress":"test2@test.com",
            "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("2008-10-08T04:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

The value  for the **dateOfBirth** field is not in **ISODate format** for one of the elements of the **Prospects** array field in the document.

I have many docs like this in my collection, which have the invalid value in different positions of the **Prospects** array field.

Also, the value , **Date(-62135751600000)** is the same in all the docs which are incorrect.

I am looking for a way to convert this date value to ISODate format, if  not at-least set it to null value.

Is there a way to **update** those  docs which have this invalid value for the date field in the collection with the ISODate value.

Comment: How exactly is it saved in the db?  it can't be type `Date` as Mongo does not support that.. it usually casted to ISODate with a "weird" value.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to do this job for you. find all wrong documents and update them:

```
const updateWrongDocuments =  () => {
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    try{
      let docs = await collection.find({"Prospects.dateOfBirth" : Date(-62135751600000)});
      for(let doc of docs) {
        for(let Prospect of doc.Prospects) {
          if(Prospect.dateOfBirth.equals(Date(-62135751600000))){
            Prospect.dateOfBirth = new Date();
          }
        }
        doc = await doc.save();
      }
      resolve('successful update!');
    }
    catch(err){
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried the find query as  you had provided directly in the Mongo GUI Client, but no docs returned. Can we directly compare the Date field like this?